# Major difference between Foreach and Using

Tags: c#, foreach

This could even be a simple question even a school boy can answer.

What is the similarities and differences between "ForEach" and "Using" (asked in an interview).

**My assumption was**

*1)Both are enumerable*

*2) Using can handle memory resources,but foreach can't.using supports IDisposable,foreach can't.*

I wish to know the answers.

Comment: the better question is..what are the similarities o.O ???

Comment: Seems almost like a trick question. They do very different things.

Comment: A question that I'd rather ask: "What's the difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerator?"

Comment: @DanThMan - I think that's the point as it's an interview question.  Evil interviewers... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarities:

- they are both logical code expansions, providing boiler-plate code of otherwise complex scenarios
- both involve a hidden variable introduced by the compiler: for the iterator and the snapshot of the disposable object, respectively

But that is about where it ends...

- `using` *demands* `IDisposable`; `foreach` *might* trigger from `IEnumerable[<T>]`, but is actually duck typed (you don't need `IEnumerable` for `foreach`)
- `using` has a predictable `try`/`finally` construct; `foreach` *might* involve a `Dispose()` if the iterator is `IEnumerable<T>`

If anything, I'd say `using` is closer to `lock` than to `foreach`.

Answer (score 8):

1. Nope
2. Nope, `foreach` will dispose of your `IEnumerable` if it implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the similarity there, with disposing of the enumerable.

Comment: in fact, IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable

Comment: @bryan: But IEnumerator does not! ha  :)

Answer (score 4):

`using` defines a scope, outside of which an object or objects will be disposed.  It does not loop or iterate.

Answer (score 4):

They both serve very different purposes.

`foreach` is made for enumerating items in a collection/array. `using` is a handy construction for making sure that you properly dispose of the thing your using. Even when exceptions are thrown for example.

Similarities for these two constructs are just, weird. Can anyone think of any similarities (apart from the very obvious: 'they are both keywords in C#')?

Comment: @Philippe: +1 for making me grin :D

Comment: There is one similarity between `foreach` and `using`: Enumerators implement `IDisposable` and a `foreach` will implicitly wrap the use of an enumerator in a `using` block. Another way of saying this is that is that a `foreach` can be recoded as a `using` block and the resulting IL will be identical.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between `foreach` and `using` is that `foreach` is used for enumerating over an `IEnumerable` whereas a `using` is used for defining a scope outside of which an object will be disposed.

There is one similarity between `foreach` and `using`: Enumerators implement `IDisposable` and a `foreach` will implicitly wrap the use of an enumerator in a `using` block. Another way of saying this is that is that a `foreach` can be recoded as a using block and the resulting IL will be identical.

The code block

```
var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
foreach(var i in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

is effectively the same as

```
var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator()) {
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent where do  you sit and think this kind of technical things???Only some born geniuos people can think so.

Comment: Note that this is not strictly true; foreach doesn't demand IDisposable on the iterator. Meaning: only the generic `IEnumerator<T>` does this; the non-generic doesn't (necessarily).

Comment: Where do you lot get the time from? :-o